# Python, Pandas - count values based on multiple criteria in row and multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = []
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sales": [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000], "Dates": pd.date_range(dt.date.today(), periods=5).astype(str)})

myDate = "2020-01-12"

def count_Commission(row):
  if (row > 3000 or df.Dates < myDate):
    return row * 0.1
  else:
    return 0

df['Commission'] = df.Sales.apply(count_Commission)
print(df)
```

I want to calculate commission base on criteria in Sales (value > 3000) and Dates (for dates earlier than myDate). I would love to see solutions with lambda and without lambda AND as a separate function or simple code (without def dedicated function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lambda:

```
df['Commission'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Sales'] * 0.1 if (row['Sales'] > 3000 or row['Dates'] < myDate) else 0, axis=1)
```

With a "dedicated function":

```
def calculate_commission(row):
    return row['Sales'] * 0.1 if (row['Sales'] > 3000 or row['Dates'] < myDate

df['Commission'] = df.apply(calculate_commission, axis=1)
```

Vectorized (fastest):

```
df['Commission'] = np.where((df['Sales'] > 3000) | (df['Dates'] < myDate), df['Sales'] * 0.1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeDifferent. It's working the way I wanted. During my attempts I was missing **row** ['Dates']

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

df['Commission'] = np.where((df.Dates<myDate) | (df.Sales>3000), df.Sales*0.1, 0)
```

As an alternative you can use `loc[...]` method:

```py
df['Commission']=0
df.loc[(df.Dates<myDate) | (df.Sales>3000), 'Commission'] = df.Sales*0.1
```

Output:

```py
   Sales       Dates  Commission
0   1000  2020-01-12         0.0
1   2000  2020-01-13         0.0
2   3000  2020-01-14         0.0
3   4000  2020-01-15       400.0
4   5000  2020-01-16       500.0
```